# facebook open graph api - filter node collection by field

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

At a high level, what I'm looking for is all of the posts a specific user has made in a group.

I can access the group feed, which contains all posts made in the group, like this:

```
GET 2.10/<group-id>/feed
```

where 2.10 is the api version I am using

I can see the author of all the posts in the feed by reading the "from" field:

```
GET 2.10/<group-id>/feed?fields=from
```

the "from" field displays a user, which is represented as a JSON object with two properties:

```
"from": {
  "name": <user_name>,
  "id": <user_id>
}
```

some collections have "read modifiers", for example on a feed that belongs to a person's profile, you can filter for only posts that have locations attached to them:

```
 GET 2.10/me/feed?with=location
```

It seems a "read modifier" on the group feed would be what is needed, however none are documented: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/group/feed

Is there any way to filter the feed so that it returns only posts by a specific author?

rephrased more generally:
is it possible to filter a collection of nodes by a node attribute?
is there another possible way to query for posts made by a specific person in a specific group?

Comment: No, no, and no. You will have to do that sort of filtering on your end.